# HTML Character Form

Tags: html, escaping, character, encode, slash

I have this text area / form:

```
<div><textarea name="subject" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Please Enter Your Subject..." required="true"></textarea></div>
```

And obviously if the user types into the text area: su/bject
Then su\bject is shown.

Is there a HTML way to make sure no '\' or any other characters apart from Aa - Zz are taken from the form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting, you can catch the result without any unwanted chars by doing this:

```
yourTextArea.value = yourTextArea.value.replace( /[^a-zA-Z]/g , '');
```

Or if you want to strip them right on key press, then modify your text area like this:

```
<textarea onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace( /[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');" name="subject" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Please Enter Your Subject..." required="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: The last one nearly works 100%..But if I have the / at the end, i.e subject/ then the slash is still added

Comment: I have edited the second one but am still getting the same problem. I am a bit confused with the first one, where exactly would I place that in my code and how would it look?

Comment: @Thomas edited the second one; the first one is just general example.